Continuity criteria in metric spaces
Let $(M, d_M)$ and $(N, d_N)$ be metric spaces. The following are the (equivalent) main characterizations o continuity for a function $f:M\to N$

$(\forall x\in M)(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)~d_M(\tilde x, x)<\delta\implies d_N(f(\tilde x), f(x))<\varepsilon$
$(\forall x\in M)(\forall (x_n)_n\in M^\infty)~x_n\to x\implies f(x_n)\to f(x)$
$(\forall Y\subset N)~Y\text{ is open/closed}\implies f^{-1}(Y)\text{ is open/closed}$

However, there are characterizations other than those. The following are two I'm aware of

$(\forall Y\subset N)~f^{-1}(\mathring Y)\subseteq \mathring{f^{-1}(Y)}$
$(\forall X\subset M)~f(\overline X)\subseteq \overline{f(X)}$

I find these to be quite elegant. Are there other interesting characterizations? I haven't found a comprehensive list anywhere.

Others that I know:

$f$ sends a convergent sequence $x_n \to x_0$ to a convergent sequence $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$.
$f$ sends a convergent sequence to a Cauchy sequence.
$f$ sends compact sets to compact sets, and the preimages of points are closed. (See this Math Overflow post.)


$(\forall Y\subset N)~Y\text{ is *}\implies f^{-1}(Y)\text{ is open},$ where * can be: (A) all open balls in $Y$; (B) all open balls in $Y$ such that their centers belong to any specified set that is dense in $Y$; (C) all sets belonging to any specified base for the topology associated with $Y$; (D) all sets belonging to any specified sub-base for the topology associated with $Y$ (feel free to add these to your list)
